# To extract each data individually in a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to read a csv file:

```
Test_read_csv.csv
Name;Forname
Dubois;Marie Anne
Duval;Julien 
Jacquet;Bernard
Martin;Lucie
```

To extract each data individually, I created the script:

```
import csv
with open("Test_read_csv.csv", "r") as file_reader:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_reader)
    #print(csv_reader.fieldnames)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row['Name'], row['Forname'])
file_reader.close()
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_read_csv.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(row['Name'], row['Forname'])
KeyError: 'Name'
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: add `csv.DictReader(file_reader, delimiter=';')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default delimiter of DictReader() function, just use:

```
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_reader, delimiter=';')
```

For further reading:

- [DictReader](https://www.foxinfotech.in/2018/09/python-dictreader-examples.html)
- [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

This should solve it. Cheers!